# How get refreshed data from observable

Tags: angular, caching, promise, ionic3, observable

I have a service that caching complete http responses. But with every call to that service that service makes a new call to the server to check for new data. If I load the page and log the data from the service (getGlobals function) it logs first the cached data and after that the new data from the service. The page however only loads the first cached data and not refresh with the new data from the server after the http call is ready.

I'll guess it has something to do with the `.then` but a `.subscribe` is not allowed on a promise. How I'll get the new response data from the server in the page with a service like getGlobals?

Service

```
    getGlobals() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let url = `${URL.getGlobals}`;
        let request = this.authHttp.get(url).map(res => res.json());
        let groupKey = 'slider';
        let ttl = 60;
        let delayType = 'all';
        let response = this.cache.loadFromDelayedObservable(url, request, groupKey, ttl , delayType);

        response.subscribe(
            data => {
                this.data = data;
                console.log(this.data); // show cache and new loaded data
                resolve(this.data);
            },
            err => {
                resolve(false);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Page

```
getGlobals(){
    this.GetApi.getGlobals().then(
        data => {
            console.log(data); // only shows the cached data 
            this.createGlobals( data );
        },
        err => console.log(err)
    );
}
```

Comment: You should use `Observable` instead of `Promise` if you want to "track" multiple changes. the `getGlobals()` function on your page will handle ONLY THE FIRST ONE response from the `getGlobals()` of Service

Comment: @hnam.pk but how!? I am not really familiair with observables

Comment: You should really learn about Observables. They have big advantages over Promises. You can learn about Observables here: https://angular.io/guide/observables